# OpenShift Origin add community cartridge

Tags: openshift-origin

I'd like to make a community cartridge available for all users. I wasn't able to find the package in yum: `yum search origin-cartridge`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c import-node -u <url to cart manifest>

## find the id
oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c list | grep <cart name>

oo-admin-ctl-cartridge -c activate --ids <id>
```